# How to accept self-signed certificate from e-mail server via smtplib (TSL)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, smtplib, starttls

My script

```
from stmplib import SMTP
con = SMTP(server, port)
con.starttls()
con.login(user, pass)
con.quit()
```

falls with error:
    `python2.7/ssl.py", line 847, in do_handshake self._sslobj.do_handshake()`

When I run command `openssl` to this server it falls with error 21: `Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)`.

I would like to know how to specify in smtplib of python option “always accept self-signed certificate when connect is established via tls to e-mail server"? 
Like I do in `requests.get` setting key `verify=False`.

**Update**
This variant with custom smtp class  and `context = ssl._create_unverified_context()` return the same error as above:

```
import smtplib
import ssl

class MySMTP(smtplib.SMTP):
    def __init__(self, host='', port=0, timeout=5):
        smtplib.SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, timeout=timeout)
        self._host = host

    def starttls(self, keyfile=None, certfile=None, context=None):
        from urllib import _have_ssl

        self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
        if not self.has_extn("starttls"):
            raise SMTPNotSupportedError("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
        (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")
        if resp == 220:
            if not _have_ssl:
                raise RuntimeError("No SSL support included in this Python")
            if context is not None and keyfile is not None:
                raise ValueError("context and keyfile arguments are mutually "
                             "exclusive")
            if context is not None and certfile is not None:
                raise ValueError("context and certfile arguments are mutually "
                             "exclusive")
            if context is None:
                context = ssl._create_stdlib_context(certfile=certfile,
                                                 keyfile=keyfile)
            self.sock = context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                                        server_hostname=self._host)
            self.file = None
            # RFC 3207:
            # The client MUST discard any knowledge obtained from
            # the server, such as the list of SMTP service extensions,
            # which was not obtained from the TLS negotiation itself.
            self.helo_resp = None
            self.ehlo_resp = None
            self.esmtp_features = {}
            self.does_esmtp = 0
        return (resp, reply)

con= MySMTP(server, port)
context  = ssl._create_unverified_context()
con.starttls(context = context)
con.login(user, pass)
con.quit()
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: The Question states 2.7

Comment: Is your self-signed certificate from a CA ( “certification authority”)?

Comment: Did you try using `ssl._https_verify_certificates(enable=False)`? (although that shouldn't affect this scenario). For the 2nd variant try `context  = ssl._create_unverified_context(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)` (or the same thing perfrmed manually after context was created: `context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE`).

Comment: Thx for try but all failed.

Comment: Could you be so kind to add the commands and their output (including the full *Pythpn* traceback)? Also what *OpenSSL* version are you using? What about *Python* (*2.7.?*)? You're saying that you are able to connect to it using requests (if yes are you connecting to the same server **app** - on the same port)? I know it's a longshot, but is the server publicly available :d ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the existing answer. Does it  answer your question? Up / down vote it.

Answer (score 12):

Late answer, but I fixed the `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)` on  `python 3.7` using `ssl._create_unverified_context()`, i.e.:

```
import smtplib, ssl
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("domain.tld", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(user, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
```

Comment: You are lucky. I have try this method early but it had not help.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! even though I had to use it on "smtp.gmail.com"

Answer (score 3):

It really seems that your approach with subclassing `SMTP` class and overriding `starttls()` method to accept `context` argument is the way to go - it's actually even introduced in Python 3.x.

However:

```
con = MySMTP(server, port)
context  = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITY_ROOT_CRT_FILE)
con.starttls(context=context)
con.login(user, pass)
con.quit()
```

should work instead of unverified context.

When you self signed your certificate you used your own certificate authority, so probably you created root CA certificate before.

This root certificate must be known to your SMTP client in order to verify your SMTP server certificate.
So find that file, put it in location accessible to your SMTP client and set this path as a value of `PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITY_ROOT_CRT_FILE`.

What you did instead was:

```
ssl._create_stdlib_context(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)
```

but `certfile` and `keyfile` are client certificate and key - some servers won't accept connections from unverified client.

Useful links:
[ssl.create_default_context() documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context)
[In case you can't find your root certificate you can start from scratch](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) (just ignore all MacOS windows on pictures - your SMTP client wants access to root certificate file - the one they add to the browser in this guide)